# Speech to Text API (NON-MOBILE)

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension, speech-to-text

I'm trying to write a program that takes in audio from the user via microphone, and then converts what's being said to text for further manipulation.

I know google has such a thing, but it's for Android developers, and I'm trying to make something more like a chrome extension (chrome extension is what I had envisioned, but I'm open to alternatives).

I've looked at the Mac OSX NSSpeechRecognizer, but I need something more comprehensive since this requires you to specify a limited grammer ahead of time.

I can't expect, or predict what my users will say into the microphone (but I CAN assume it will be English).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google have an unofficial API, which can be used as described in this post:
http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/

If you're writing a chrome extension, you might be able to use a tag like:

```
<input type="text" x-webkit-speech />
```

which adds the microphone button and uses google's cloud speech-recognition to fill the text box with what the user says.

Comment: Wow thank you!  I actually needed this about a week ago, but this is exactly what I was looking for and it will help me move forward on another project.  Thanks!